# Freeing memory allocated to the heap stored inside a vector

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

I have created a vector by allocating it's memory to the heap. I then create 10 string objects also allocated to heap memory and store them inside the vector. I've tried to free that memory associated with each new string object, using the `delete` operator, but I'm not how to do it. I'm using C++ 11.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   vector<string> *v = new vector<string>;

   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     // allocate a new string object on the heap
     string *a = new string("Hello World");
     //de-reference the string object
     v->push_back(*a);
   }

  // show the contents of the vector
  for(auto i = v->begin(); i != v->end(); ++i) {
    // okay so this makes a lot more sense than:
    // const string &s = *i;
    // this way we create a pointer to a string object
    // it is a lot more clear this way
    const string *s = &(*i);
    cout << *s << " " << s->length() << endl;
  }

  cout << endl << endl;

  for(vector<string>::iterator it = v->begin(); it != v->end(); ++it) {
    delete &it;
    v->erase(it);
  }

  for(auto i = v->begin(); i != v->end(); ++i) {
   cout << *i << endl;
  }
  cout << endl << "Size: " << v->size() << endl;

  delete v;
}
```

`g++ -std=c++11 main.cc -o main`

My error is that not all objects are being removed. I end up with 5 objects left after the last 4 statement. I expect to have zero objects inside the vector once these operations are done.

My output:

```
Hello World 11
Hello World 11
Hello World 11
Hello World 11
Hello World 11
Hello World 11
Hello World 11
Hello World 11
Hello World 11
Hello World 11


Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Size: 5
```

The problem is that not all objects are being deleted.

Comment: Why are you allocating the vector dynamically? There is no reason to do that. You shouldn't need to perform any manual memory management at all.

Comment: This is for educational purposes. What I am doing is futile except for me learning.

Comment: Just remove all of your pointer and all of your news and it'll work the way you want it to.

Comment: That first for loop is memory leak heaven. Not to mention all this dynamic allocation is error prone and useless. Containers are there precisely to handle this for you. `*new X();` is "memory leak operator" btw, and that's what you do in that for loop up there.

Comment: @self - `This is for educational purposes.`  It isn't hard -- what you allocate with `new/new[]` you deallocate with `delete/delete[]`.  All you're really learning (if you can call it learning) is how to write a gauntlet of code so that you deallocate what you allocated.

Answer (score 4):

I think the particular problem you are worrying about in the myriad of problem is your for loop is not removing all the items, ie:

```
for(vector<string>::iterator it = v->begin(); it != v->end(); ++it) {
  delete &it;
  v->erase(it);
}
```

Your issue is that you are changing the vector you are iterating over, which leads to undefined behavior which is showing itself as you are not deleting all the values. (A vector's iterator is only valid as long as you don't add or remove values).

I *can* explain why it is only doing 5, but the answer would not be cross platform. The compiler is free to do whatever it wants in this case. It would be just as valid for the compiler to cause demons to fly out of your nose.

Basically, you're erasing a value, and them moving to the next index. So you erase whats at 0, which will pull what is at 1 to what is at 0. Then you move to index 1, which contains what used to be in index 2. Then you remove it. Essentially, you remove all the even indexes form the vector.

Edit: Reducing the problem to a minimal reproducable:

```
std::vector<int> vals;

for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++0) vals.push_back(i);

for (std::vector<int>::iterator i = vals.begin(); i != vals.end(); ++i)
{
   vals.erase(i);//after this point, i's behavior is undefined!
}
```

Edit 3: Enumeration of all problems with code (suggested action based on Meta conversation)

1. Vector already allocates its collection memory in the heap (everything except the pointer to the memory and the size counters). This whole approach is based on not understanding that fact. new vector does put the whole vector in the heap, which may be what OP wanted.
2. string also, allocates its memory in the heap. `new std::string` will simply allocate the pointer to the character array and the size in the heap. So thats also something to note.
3. If you want to have a vector of pointers, you should have `std::vector<T*>`. `std::vector<T>` will be a vector of instances of `T`.
4. Since the vector's memory is already allocated on the heap, this would initially seem like an effort in futility. **However, there ARE instances where you MAY want such a structure.** For example, a polymorphic type would have to be stored in this way in order to avoid slicing. (I'd use a smart pointer however, but for educational purposes that is a good exercise).
5. in loop 1, you dynamically allocate a string. You then use a copy constructor to instantiate a solid instance in the vector. You then let the pointer go out of scope. This is a memory leak and an inefficient copy.
6. You seem to really want to use pointers as references. `std::string& s = *it` is much more readable than taking the address.
7. juanchopanza correctly noted that you are deleting the location of the iterator, which is more undefined behavior. `&it` is of type `std::vector<string>::iterator*`. Why this is probably not crashing and burning is that the iterator type is only comprised of builtin types and you're not doing too much after this (you've probably set yourself up for some delicious stack corruption). If you had a `std::vector<T*>` (matching item 1) with the vector having sole ownership, you'd want to do this to clean it up:

`delete &(*it);`

But it would be much better to do something like `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` and never worry about it.

6. Never-ever-ever use a global using std.

Comment: @juanchopanza good point...what happens is MORE NASAL DEAMONS.

Comment: `delete &(*it)` is just as bad as `delete &it`.  Both of them are destroying an object which is managed by someone else.  If you have a vector of pointers, then `delete *it` may be the correct thing to do.

Comment: @BenVoigt wow its been a while. I believe that is why I said "in the actual heap code" but i'll change that to make it more clear.

Comment: The `std::vector<T*>` case is exactly when you should `delete *it;`  `delete &(*it)` might possibly make sense inside the vector implementation, but never for user code.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that not all objects are being deleted.

That is because you are leaking the strings when you populate the vector.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  string *a = new string("Hello World"); // Leak: who deletes a? Nobody!
  v->push_back(*a);
}
```

This would be a way to avoid that particular leak:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  v->push_back("Hello World");
}
```

Still, you are dynamically allocating the `v`, and there is no reason to do that. This would be a simpler and idiomatic way to do this in C++. It does not involve memory leaks or undefined behaviour, unlike your version:

```
int main()
{
   vector<string> v(10, "Hello World");

   for (auto& s : v)
     cout << s.length() << endl;
}
```

You don't need pointers. You don't need to call `new`. You don't need to worry about memory management.

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing a copy of the string on the vector when you use the v->push_back(*a); command.  If you don't want to do this, you will need to make your vector a vector of string pointers, then push the pointers themselves onto the vector.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are allocating string dynamically even though you are storing it in vector by value.This snippet doesn't make sense even for educational purpose unless you are learning how to leak memory in C++.

```
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     // allocate a new string object on the heap
     string *a = new string("Hello World");
     //de-reference the string object
     v->push_back(*a);
   }
```

If you want to store pointers in any stl container then I would suggest use some smart pointers ( EXCLUDING AUTO_PTR ) like boost::shared_ptr. They take care of memory management for you.